# How to hide a JPanel with a action in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have got this bit so far but I keep getting errors. I don't now what is happening, I have looked for tutorials online, but I don't now how to fix my problem.

```
JComboBox<String> cmdChoose = new JComboBox<String>();
    cmdChoose.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (cmdChoose.getSelectedItem() == "Json Sign") {

                /* I am getting the error here it is below it says mDataone
                  cannot be resolved so please help me! */

                mDataone.setVisible(true);
            }

            if (cmdChoose.getSelectedItem() == "Summon") {

            }
        }
    });

    cmdChoose.setBounds(149, 11, 181, 27);
    mainPage.getContentPane().add(cmdChoose);

    cmdChoose.addItem("Json Sign");
    cmdChoose.addItem("Summon");

    cmdChoose.setSelectedItem(null);

    Label cglbl = new Label("Command Generators:");
    cglbl.setBounds(10, 16, 133, 22);
    mainPage.getContentPane().add(cglbl);

    JPanel mDataone = new JPanel();
    mDataone.setBounds(10, 74, 324, 209);
    mainPage.getContentPane().add(mDataone);
    mDataone.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));
```

Comment: Well, the message is pretty clear, isn't it? Where do you define `mDataone`? 10 lines **after**. So it's not defined at that point. As simple as that. Also, learn how to compare Strings in Java.

Comment: `JPanel mDataone = new JPanel();` is defined AFTER you define the `ActionListener`, so the `ActionListener` can not see it.  `mDataone` is also defined within a local context, which could have issues

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created an inner class for handling the action and the mDataone is declared after it, so create it before handling the action event, but the best way is to make it static.

One more thing that you should do in your code is that you should use equals() or equalsIgnoreCase(), cmdChoose.getSelectedItem().equalsIgnoreCase("Json Sign"). Hope it helps...

Comment: *"..the best way is to make it static."* No it isn't. Using `static` for GUI components causes more problems than it fixes, and is more often a sign of poor design.

Comment: it will work just fine for the problem at hand, but yes you are right Andrew, it is a sign of poor design...

Answer (score 0):

You are making the JPanel **mdataone** to be visible before attaching it to your JFrame. You have put the declaration of the JPanel at the end of the code, so when the **setVisible**() method is called in ActionPerformed() method then you get an error saying that **mdataone** is not defined. So to resolve this error you need to place the below code from its actual place (i.e. from the end) to the above of the **actionPerformed**() method.

```
    JPanel mDataone = new JPanel();
    mDataone.setBounds(10, 74, 324, 209);
    mainPage.getContentPane().add(mDataone);
    mDataone.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));
```

Comment: so i need to put the action performed after the creation of the JPanel?

Answer (score -1):

Like this?

```
JPanel mDataone = new JPanel();
    mDataone.setBounds(10, 74, 324, 209);
    mainPage.getContentPane().add(mDataone);
    mDataone.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
    mDataone.add(tabbedPane);

    JPanel first_line = new JPanel();
    tabbedPane.addTab("1st Line", null, first_line, null);

    JPanel second_line = new JPanel();
    tabbedPane.addTab("2nd Line", null, second_line, null);

    JPanel third_line = new JPanel();
    tabbedPane.addTab("3rd Line", null, third_line, null);

    JPanel forth_line = new JPanel();
    tabbedPane.addTab("4th Line", null, forth_line, null);

    JComboBox<String> cmdChoose = new JComboBox<String>();
    cmdChoose.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (cmdChoose.getSelectedItem() == "Json Sign") {
                mDataone.setVisible(true);
            }

            if (cmdChoose.getSelectedItem() == "Summon") {

            }
        }
    });

    cmdChoose.setBounds(149, 11, 181, 27);
    mainPage.getContentPane().add(cmdChoose);

    cmdChoose.addItem("Json Sign");
    cmdChoose.addItem("Summon");

    cmdChoose.setSelectedItem(null);
```

Comment: I new to this site and it worked also i really like this site already!!!!

Comment: You missed the point about NOT using "==" for String comparisons.

Comment: `and it worked also` - then don't forget to "accept" the answer that helped you solve your problem by clicking on the checkmark, so people know the problem has been solved.